# connecting to sqlite database from phonegap html file for android

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile, cordova

I am using phonegap and sqlite to develop cross-platform mobile app for android,ios,blackberry.For reference i am using http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html.  My index.html is below

1.i have got phonegap.jar in  lib

2.got phonegap.js in assests/wwww

3.got sqlite browser and sql shell downloaded in my hardisk

4.got jquery.min.js

I would like to know how to give the location of my sqlite from index.html so that it can make a connection with it. If I just pass in phonegap.js it is not making connection to sqlite.

```
<head>
 <title>Contact Example</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap-1.4.0.js">    </script>      
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"/></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     function onLoad(){
       document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
    var db = window.openDatabase("Dummy_DB", "3.0", "Just a Dummy DB",200000); 
            alert("db="+db); //not printing
 }
 function onDeviceReady(){
      navigator.notification.alert("doo");//only printing this


 }
```

```
 <body onload="c()">
  <h1>n Example</h1>
  <p>Database</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of possible problems:

- When you call `openDatabase` the document has loaded, but *phonegap*
  has not. The problem is that you call the method `c()` `onBodyLoad`
  not `onDeviceReady` as advised in the phonegap tutorial. See
  [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#deviceready).
- Please also check you add the javascript accordingly. A very good way
  to check is to add the eventListener for deviceready. If it gets
  fired the javascript is loaded ok.

Comment: for accesing sqlite databasedo  i just need to include phonegap.js and phonegap.jar or do i need to tell my application where sqlite is which i have downloaded

Comment: Phone gap has a default where the database is - it has its own database to manage (it creates it and maintains it). If you want to connect to existing database you might find this thread useful: http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/5e57a728dc66a2a1?pli=1.

Comment: so to create a new db in sqlite phonegap i just need to use window.openDatabase.? also I added listener and device ready but it is giving  Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:13 ..in log...

Comment: If this is the updated code then still you have the same problem - `addEventListener` is done outside the `onLoad` body see the example in the documentation I pointed you to. The database is created yes: see here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#openDatabase 'This method will create a new SQL Lite Database and return a Database object. Use the Database Object to manipulate the data.'

Comment: i have connected my existing database with my html file but if i will upload it to phonegap build.It will generate new database at run time(what i think).Can you tell me is it possible to add my database with html file and upload it to phonegap so that it can generate app for different platform linked to my database.

Comment: I am not aware of such a way, but never sought for it explicitly. If you want platform-by-platform solution refer to the link from my first comment.