# How to Read & Write in Internal DataBase with PhoneGap?

Tags: android, html, sqlite, cordova

I have an internal SQLite DB under **"Assets"** Folder in which i have stored 100 usernames & corresponding Passwords, How do i access it via phoneGap.? 
 I have read

- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage
- [connecting to sqlite database from phonegap html file for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171662/connecting-to-sqlite-database-from-phonegap-html-file-for-android)
- http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494756/Adding-SQL-Database-support-to-your-iPhone-App

  Am still not able to figure out How to connect to my internal DB which is already Created, 
  **dbname = userauth
  Tablename = reg
  parameters = usrnm ,  psw**
   <s>Any</s> Answer is Highly Encouraged
  **Am using this here**.
   [image: Login Screen]

Comment: from your tags, I assume you are on Android platform, right? therefore, the 3rd link is unrelated.

Comment: Just a reference, of course i found more than 15 links, but none of them Solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Creates / Opens a connection to DB
 */
DB.openDB = function() {
    try {
        if (!window.openDatabase) {
            //alert('Cannot open database!');
        } else {
            var shortName = 'db_name';
            var version = '1.0';
            var displayName = 'DBNAME';
            var maxSize = (DEVICE_TYPE == DEVICE_ANDROID || DEVICE_TYPE == DEVICE_ANDROID_TAB) ? 5242880 : 1000000; ////819200; //65536; // in bytes // increased to support Android//163840; // 
            this.vocabDB = window.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize, this.DBCreated);
            this.DBSupported = true;
        }
    } catch(e) {
        //console.log("DB Error handling code goes here.");
        //console.log(e);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do a window.openDatabase() to a database in the assets folder. You'll need to copy it to the right place so that the WebView will load it. Check out this:

http://gauravstomar.blogspot.ca/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+(Gaurav+S+Tomar+:+Bootstrapping+Intelligence)

post as Gaurav gives you code to do this on both Android and iOS.

Comment: Referred that too, But will try again & again ... am in Critical Situation, based on this solution i have to decide either to Continue with PhoneGap or Native. Finding Difficult to solve each issue