# Android app, not native, what to use

Tags: android, cordova, trigger.io

I don't really want to use the native andorid for few reasons
so i started with [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) as it gives me flexibility to port
the application to other platforms easily and can built apps in languages
i know better.
But then people say its really slow, better way is to built native app
for every platform.

Some one told to try [trigger.io](https://trigger.io/) which is ( his say) is faster than Phonegap.

I think building native would have the best performance gain, no comparison.
But wanted to know are applications built with these cross platform solutions are really
slow and its like not useful or say not compete-able ?

Have anyone really compared it with native and have some kind of results?
I found this [comparison chart](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AsTInFQpmXDNdEdJU0ZNNGx3dDA3aXAxV3lXYWhXVHc) which is not really useful.

Also i made my simple first app in phonegap and native android, but i really
did not find any performance difference (App to take picture using camera and compressing
it to a thumbnail size, displaying and storing)

So what do you suggest to start with or go native way and built explicitly for every platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently also turned from phonegap to native. My opinion is that phonegap is suitable for simple apps which actually looks and behaves like webpages..But if you want to add to your app some specific things, using PhoneGap is not a good approach. (My issue was with background services, Google maps performance)..There are native plugins for phonegap, but I decided better to write native apps and maybe some simple app with less functionality for other platforms like Symbian, which do not worth writing native one..

Other problem of PhoneGap is, that is runs pretty smooth on iPhone and Android, but other platforms are worse in performance and features functionality (I have experiences with poor performance on Symbian).

UI is really simplier to customize in PhoneGap, but you should keep design of every platform..Iphone styled apps would be a sore thumb for Windows Phone users.

So..I really prefer going native,your app will be better..Multiplatform only when you have small budget, simple app, lack of time and you need provide app for all platforms..

Answer (score 0):

I have tried building App using PhoneGap. since my project deals with requirements with third parties I was not allowed to use PhoneGap because of the performance issue when compared with Native. Here is one of my answer which can solve your doubts https://stackoverflow.com/a/10971241/1008278